# Interval jQuery .css

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this code which sets the .css value of a div

```
$("#1").mouseover(function () {
   $("#naam").css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

I want an interval of a X amount of time on it.

Comment: An interval for doing what? I guess you mean a delay

Comment: Yes a delay sorry =((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#1").mouseover(
    setTimeout(function () {
        function() { 
            $("#naam").css('visibility','visible');
        }
    },30000);
);
```

Comment: You need to use `setTimeout` not `setInterval` . It execute on every 30 sec interval

Answer (score 4):

You could use `delay()`:

```
$("#1").mouseover(function () {
    $("#naam").finish().delay(2000).show(0);
});
```

Or use `setTimeout()`

As not stipulated in DOC but AFAIK, `.finish()` (jq 1.9+) clears any previous running delay applied to element.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, what you want is `.delay()` :

```
$( "#1" ).mouseover(function() {
    $( "#naam" ).delay( 800 ).show(0);
});
```

The document is here:
https://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Indeed, you need `.show(0)` or no animation will be put in queue